# How to clear the value of picklist field with a formula field

Tags: formula, picklist

I have an action on the Account object where I want to update some values on the record. In some conditions I want to force the user to re-select a value for a picklist field (Account Country).  My plan was to *pre-define* a value for the field where I clear the picklist if the {Conditions} are true, otherwise I leave the value that is already selected.
Here is my formula for pre-defining the picklist field (the Conditions part works fine, just excluded all the details)

```
IF ({Conditions},
" ",
TEXT(Account.Account_country__c))
```

I've tried the following options to clear the picklist field:

- " " (with a space)
- "" (no space)
- "BLANK"
- "NULL"
- "--None--"
- null

And nothing works.  Any ideas?

Comment: What is the return type of your formula?

Comment: it's not a formula field, it's a formula to prepopulate a value of the field as part of the Action.  So in that respect, the return type is a picklist value since the field is a picklist field.

Comment: Can you please check that the picklist does not set a default value?

Comment: By "Action" do you mean you're invoking a screen flow with an Action Button? If so, I think you may need to show your flow logic to understand what the issue is. If not, then I'm not sure what you mean by Action. Is it an Update Action using a URL hack?

Answer (score 0):

Could you try setting it to the actual null value rather than "NULL" in quotes.

It would look something like:
`IF ({Conditions}, null, TEXT(Account.Account_country__c))`

rather than, `IF ({Conditions}, "NULL", TEXT(Account.Account_country__c))`

Comment: I tried that, and it doesn't work :(

Comment: Make sure the 'Restrict picklist to the values defined in the value set' is set to false

Comment: I'm using a Picklist Value Set, so am not able to change this setting on the actual object itself

Comment: ah - but that seems to be the issue!  I created a test picklist that does NOT use a Picklist Value Set and now I get the behavior I am expecting using " "!